# Validação usando Remote na classe "PaI"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho minha classe Pessoa, nela possui a propriedade CPF

```
public class Pessoa {
   public string Cpf {get;set;}
}
```

Outras classes herdam dela, como por exemplo, a classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente : Pessoa {
}
```

Acontece é que eu utilizo o `Data Annotation Remote`

```
[Remote("CheckCpf", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Mensagem.")]
```

Como eu posso usar o `Remote` validando em cada classe que herda de Pessoa ?

Por exemplo:
Cliente:

```
 [Remote("CheckCpfCLIENTE", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Mensagem.")]
```

Fornecedor:

```
 [Remote("CheckCpfFornecedor", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Mensagem.")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Remote` supõe que a validação é no *Controller*, não no *Model*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx).

Conforme sua pergunta, você possui um `ValidationController` que possui o método de validação, o que está correto se o intuito é validar por JavaScript. Se o intuito é validar ao persistir o registro de fato, é preciso implementar um atributo de CPF que faça a validação em *Model*.

Um exemplo de atributo de validação por CPF do tipo `string` está abaixo, considerando pontos e traços:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using SeuProjeto.Models;

namespace SeuProjeto.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
    sealed public class CpfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private MaxiMailContext context = new MaxiMailContext();

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;

            int soma = 0, resto = 0;
            string digito;
            int[] multiplicador1 = new int[9] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
            int[] multiplicador2 = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

            string CPF = value.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");

            if (CPF.Length != 11)
                return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");

            if (Convert.ToUInt64(CPF) % 11111111111 == 0)
                return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");

            decimal CPFDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(CPF);


            /* if (validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType() == typeof(Customer))
            {
                var model = (Customer)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

                if (context.Customers.Any(c => (c.CPF == CPFDecimal) && (c.CustomerId != model.CustomerId)))
                {
                    var message = FormatErrorMessage("CPF já está cadastrado em outra conta de cliente.");
                    return new ValidationResult(message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (context.Customers.Any(c => (c.CPF == CPFDecimal)))
                {
                    var message = FormatErrorMessage("CPF já está cadastrado em outra conta de cliente.");
                    return new ValidationResult(message);
                }
            } */

            string tempCpf = CPF.Substring(0, 9);

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];

            resto = soma % 11;
            if (resto < 2)
                resto = 0;
            else
                resto = 11 - resto;

            digito = resto.ToString();
            tempCpf = tempCpf + digito;
            soma = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];

            resto = soma % 11;

            if (resto < 2)
                resto = 0;
            else
                resto = 11 - resto;

            digito = digito + resto.ToString();

            if (CPF.EndsWith(digito))
                return null;
            else
                return new ValidationResult("CPF Inválido.");
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: o código de validação é feito no controller "Validation", meu problema é que, na action CheckCpf, eu passo no meu db.Cliente.where(x => x.cpf == cpf.. se for fornecedor ou algo... mas como eu tenho o CPF no Pessoa, como vou fazer isso ?

Comment: @Rod Se CPF existe no *Model* `Pessoa`, é nela que você vai verificar. Se cada *Model* possui seu campo CPF, é preciso fazer um método diferente para cada *Controller*.

Comment: vou responder o que eu fiz aqui, a principio funcionou...gostaria de opiniões

Comment: @Rod Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: da uma olhada na resposta que publiquei

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso é buscando diretamente com ADO.Net mas aconselho a usar um ORM. Você está trabalhando com algum ORM? NHibernate ou EF.

Caso esteja me informe que tento mostrar como fazer. Mande o código do seu remote validation também.

Dê uma olhada também no meu blog. Fiz um post lá que respondeu a uma pergunta aqui sobre remote validation. Lembre-se de validar sempre o ID também pois caso não faça isso você terá problemas para alterar seus objetos pois vai constar que já existe no BD.

Lá você poderá baixar um projeto em asp net mvc 5 com o remote validation funcionando também.
http://blogdoquintal.net/2015/01/06/fazendo-validacao-ajax-no-servidor-com-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Olá @Marco, meu problema não é a validação, e sim na herança de propriedades

Comment: Então faça o que o Cigano ai embaixo falou.

Comment: não faz sentido isso, vou ver o que faço

Answer (score 1):

Como todas as classes que herdam de pessoa, também tem a propriedade CPF, fiz da seguinte maneira:

Na classe Pessoa deixo minha propriedade CPF como virtual

```
public virtual string CPF {get;set;}
```

Na minha classe Cliente por exemplo, eu faço um override na propriedade CPF de pessoa:

```
    [Remote("CheckCpfCliente", "Cliente", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Mensagem erro")]
    public override string CPF
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CnpjCpf;
        }
        set
        {
            base.CnpjCpf = value;
        }
    }
```

e faço a mesma coisa em demais classes que herdam de Pessoa, mudando apenas a "Action" e "Controller" do remote

```
  [Remote("CheckCpfFORNECEDOR, "FORNECEDOR")
  [Remote("CheckCpfFUNCIONARIO, "FUNCIONARIO")
```

etc

Comment: Na verdade isso só prova um furo de design do próprio ASP.NET MVC, em que você precisa necessariamente definir um método diferente de validação para cada entidade derivada de `Pessoa`. O ganho da sua aplicação com isso é perto de nenhum.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pois é, a sua validação que você postou, através de um atributo, é só no server né? Eu gostaria de usar Remote pelo fato dele validar ainda no cliente

Comment: É só você adaptar o atributo pra ele virar um método de *Controller*.